# Is there a way I can process CSVs with a parent child relationship using NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, csv

I have a record that looks like this

```
name, value

Parent Name
MyName, MyValue

Parent Name
OtherName, OtherValue
```

This should translate into

```
[
  {
    name:"ParentName",
    children: [
      {
        name: "myName",
        value: "myValue"
      },{
        name: "otherName",
        value: "otherValue"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Now I know this is poorly put together CSV but I can't control that so I need to use it as it currently is done. I could preprocess it but I am not sure how I would tell if it is the parent line or a child line.

Is there a good way to parse these sorts of documents using Node?

Comment: Why does it show "Parent Name" in one place and "ParentName" in another?

Comment: Since this is completely non-standard, you will just have to write your own parsing code and logic.  It's not clear what else you're asking beyond that.

Comment: That was what I was kind of getting at does this match a common pattern of is it random

Comment: This isn't "poorly put together" data, it's just flat out "not CSV data". CSV is at most a single line of header information (naming each column, with commas between the names) and then each next line is -unsurprisingly- comma separated values. No empty lines, no "suddenly, new names". Just row after row of comma separated values.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a CSV format by any definition of such format.  As such, you're not going to find any ready-made CSV code to parse this or to put it into your desired output.

Instead, you're going to have to write your own code to read it, parse it and organize it the way you want the output.